# Ajax PUT Request »Request Method:OPTIONS«

Tags: ajax, rest, put

I'd like to send a PUT Request to my API. When Server and Client are on one machine, everything works just fine.
When the API is on a remote Server then I get a 404 Error. (But the URL is right and the API is working as well; I checked that with PostMan (a REST Client App for Chrome)). 
The Request Method is shown in DevTools as:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
```

After searching the web I found out that it has something to to with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

so I changed the API Response to the above example.

Here is the complete output of the headers:

```
Request URL:http://example.org/api
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
**Request Headers**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:example.org
Origin:http://localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/svpoffline/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu         Chromium/31.0.1650.63 Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
**Response Headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Custom-Header
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:368
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 25 Dec 2013 23:47:35 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=1, max=100
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.21-nmm1
```

Comment: Are you making the Ajax request from the same domain the service is hosted on? If not, you might be running into a cross domain issue.

Comment: No, the domains are not the same. When everything is on my local machine (localhost) then it works perfectly. So my code is not broken or something like that. 

I guess that it is a cross domain issue, but how can I solve it? Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" does not help.